# How to center text and buttons in QMessageBox widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qmessagebox

I'm making a QMessageBox and was having trouble centering the text and the buttons in the pop up window.

This is the code that I have for the message box:

```
def update_msgbox(self):
        self.msg = QMessageBox(self.centralwidget)
        self.msg.setWindowTitle("  Software Update")
        self.msg.setText("A software update is available. \nDo you want to update now?")
        self.msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
        self.msg.setStyleSheet("QLabel{min-width: 200px;}")
        self.msg.exec_()
```

and this is the way the popup window currently looks:

[image]

Is there a way to center the text and to center the buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution is to remove (or delete if necessary) the elements and add them back to the layout:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox, QLabel, QDialogButtonBox


class MessageBox(QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        grid_layout = self.layout()

        qt_msgboxex_icon_label = self.findChild(QLabel, "qt_msgboxex_icon_label")
        qt_msgboxex_icon_label.deleteLater()

        qt_msgbox_label = self.findChild(QLabel, "qt_msgbox_label")
        qt_msgbox_label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid_layout.removeWidget(qt_msgbox_label)

        qt_msgbox_buttonbox = self.findChild(QDialogButtonBox, "qt_msgbox_buttonbox")
        grid_layout.removeWidget(qt_msgbox_buttonbox)

        grid_layout.addWidget(qt_msgbox_label, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        grid_layout.addWidget(qt_msgbox_buttonbox, 1, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])

    msg = MessageBox()

    msg.setWindowTitle("Software Update")
    msg.setText("A software update is available.<br>Do you want to update now?")
    msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Cancel)
    msg.setStyleSheet("QLabel{min-width: 200px;}")

    msg.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That seems to work. I'm assuming that if you gave that answer then there's no standard way to do it?

Comment: @yem Exactly, there is no regular way to do it unfortunately